# Mostrar mas de 1 parametro dentro de un collection select Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He estado intentando desde hace un rato intentar mostrar mas de un parametro dentro de un collection select, sin embargo no he logrado resolverlo, el collection lo estoy mostrando de la siguiente manera:

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, { include_blank: "" } %>
```

Y me despliega un select unicamente con el nombre del cliente, obviamente dado que solo estoy pasandole el nombre asociado a su id:

```
Select ->
Juan
Carlos
Raul
```

Sin embargo me gustaria mostrar uno o 2 atributos mas a la hora de desplegarse, como su ciudad, numero de identificacion, algo parecido a:

```
Select ->
Juan < 87654321 . Madrid >
Carlos < 98765432 . Bogota >
Raul < 23456789 . Mexico >
```

¡Agradezco puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar un método en `Customer` para concatenar la información que quieres mostrar; por ejemplo (asumiendo que los atributos extras se llaman `id` y `city`):

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def select_attributes
    "#{name} < #{id} . #{city} >"
  end

  # ...
end
```

Y utiliza ese método en lugar de `name` en el `collection_select`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :select_attributes, { include_blank: "" } %>
```

Comment: ¡Tremendo Gerry! Te agradezco muchisimo! =D